# Show Hashtags from one user on Instagram

Tags: jquery, instagram, hashtag

I have a website where i want to show a number of hashtags from a single user on Instagram using Jquery (Javascript), is that possible? and if it so, how can i do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, you can client-side. In practice, you cannot.

The `/users/{user_id}/media/recent` endpoint, which you would need, is acessible without user authentication. Therefore, you do not need to generate an access token; you only need a client ID:

> For the most part, Instagram’s API only requires the use of a `client_id`. A `client_id` simply associates your server, script, or program with a specific application.

You can "scrape" this endpoint's content (using [JSONP responses](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/#jsonp)) and then paginate through the user's entire Instagram feed. Once you do that, you can count how many times the user has used a hashtag.

There are two problems with this approach:

1. It'll be slow. Each and every visitor to your Web site needs to send one or more requests to Instagram to retrieve the data. This takes time and consumes your visitors' bandwidth.
2. It'll stop working. Instagram doesn't want you burning precious CPU cycles requesting the same data over and over again, so to prevent excessive use like this, the API [limits applications to 5,000 requests per hour](http://instagram.com/developer/limits/).

Solution: Use a server-side library instead and cache the post-processed results.